# Insert New Record into MyDB in Android Eclipse

Tags: android, database

I make a new project sample but some problems.

**Step 1**: create a new class for database:

```
package com.isummation.customgallery;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    static final String dbName = "attach.db";
    static final String bankTable = "bank";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, dbName, null, 33);
    }

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE admin (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, username TEXT, password TEXT, sec_question TEXT, sec_answer TEXT)");

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE [bank] ([id] INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY NULL,[old_file_address] TEXT  NULL,[filename] TEXT  NULL,[thumnail] TEXT  NULL,[ext] TEXT  NULL)");

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE [enc] ([id] INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,[MasterKey] TEXT  NULL)");
}

public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + bankTable);
        // db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + deptTable);
        // db.execSQL("DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS dept_id_trigger");
        // db.execSQL("DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS dept_id_trigger22");
        // db.execSQL("DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS fk_empdept_deptid");
        // db.execSQL("DROP VIEW IF EXISTS " + viewEmps);
        // onCreate(db);
    }

    public void InsertNew(String FileAddr, String FileName, String thumbnail,
            String Ext) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("insert into bank values('','" + FileAddr + "','" + FileName
                + "','" + thumbnail + "','" + Ext + "')");
        // ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        // cv.put("old_file_address", FileAddr);
        // cv.put("filename", FileName);
        // cv.put("thumbnail", thumbnail);
        // cv.put("Ext", Ext);
        // db.insert(bankTable, null, cv);
        db.close();
    }

    public Cursor BindAll() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("select * from bank", new String[] {});
        return cur;
    }
}
```

**Step 2**: use "InsertNew" function in my activity class

```
DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
db.InsertNew("test", "test", "test", "test");
```

The `bank` table has 5 columns as

- ID : Primary Key
- name 1 : text
- name 1 : text
- name 1 : text
- name 1 : text

I have 5 columns but I have to set 4 columns without "ID" because this is primary key.

Questions:

1. No records are added to the database. What's wrong with my code?
2. If I want do not create database in "onCreate", how can load database from my `Assets` folder?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple solution for you, check GreenDao Generator, you will see how helpfull it can be.

> http://greendao-orm.com/

Cheers